# How Can I use Multiple cookies from Different user type Logins (Login from CSV file in a single thread) in other thread groups randomly?

Tags: multithreading, authentication, jmeter, session-cookies, beanshell

I have 4 different action types and I want to run 2 action with USER 1 and another 2 Action with USER 2.
I have set up two differet threads for 2 Logins and then used these cookies in 4 different actions randomly using Beanshell post processor and Beanshell preprocessor methods.
But now I want to use single thread for Login request and allow users login with CSV data. In this case how can I get the different cookie for each Login s that I can pass them randomly in 4 actions ?
Please help.

Comment: Place the code you are using now here

Answer (score 0):

Given you have cookies defined like:

```
cookie_1=Cookie #1
cookie_2=Cookie #2
cookie_3=Cookie #3
cookie_4=Cookie #4
```

You can use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combination in order to get a random cookie value like:

```
 ${__P(cookie_${__Random(1,4,)},)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Random and Property combination]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.